# How to disabled selected date (asp.net mvc4)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I  am trying to make an appointment page in MVC4. It is working well but I would like to disable the date which is chosen. Here is my controller to make an appointment:

```
public ActionResult Make()
       {
           return View();
       }
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult Make(Models.AppModel User)
       {
           if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
           {
               using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
               {
                   var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);

                   var app = new Appointment();

                   app.Date = (DateTime)User.Date;
                   app.Description = User.Description;
                   app.Status = "isPending";
                   app.PatientNo = patient.PatientNo;
                   app.AppNo = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
                   db.Appointments.InsertOnSubmit(app);
                   db.SubmitChanges();

               }
           }
           else
           {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
           }
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient");
       }
       //
   }
}
```

and here is my view with the datepicker

```
@model DentAppSys.Models.AppModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Appointment";
}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "");
    <div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Get an Appointment</legend>


            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Date)</div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "DatePicker" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Date)

            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Description)</div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Description)

            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="footer_btn" />

        </fieldset>

    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DatePicker").datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want `@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "DatePicker", disabled="true" })`

Comment: @Kunukn: `readonly=true` might be more appropriate here. Better readability, and the value still gets submitted with the form.

Comment: @Flater readonly is a reserved keyword, so it is @readonly=true :)

Comment: @Kunukn: Spot on. Those types of things I generally only notice when VS alerts me :)

Answer (score 1):

seems to me your TextBoxFor for "Date" may be disable depends on condition.
you may try this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "");
            <div>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Get an Appointment</legend>


                    <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Date)</div>
                        <div>
        @{
string idAttr="";
        if(condition_for_disable==true)
        {
idAttr="DatePicker";
}
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = idAttr })

          }                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Date)

                        </div>

                    <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Description)</div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Description)

                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="footer_btn" />

                </fieldset>

            </div>
        }


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DatePicker").datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: but where can i add my connection to database to check if that date is already choosen?

Comment: in that case the if condition may be like if(Model.Date>DateTime.MinValue) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "DatePicker", disabled="disabled" })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "DatePicker", @readonly="true" })
```

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "DatePicker", @readonly="true" })
  ...   I used this one.I choose 22 may and created appointment when i go appointment page 22 may is not disabled????

Comment: For your case you should use `disabled="disabled"`. As readonly will make the text readonly but still the datepicker events will work and can change date. Use `disabled="disabled"` and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it on JavaScript code..
Hope so it helps..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DatePicker").datepicker();

        $("#DatePicker").attr('disabled','disabled')

    });

</script>
```

this above is to disable a all datepicker whose id: #DatePicker
So,update code after your comment:

```
$('#DatePicker').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
       var bDisable = arrayDisabledDates[dt];
       if (bDisable) 
          return [false, '', ''];
       else 
          return [true, '', ''];
   }
});
```

and arrayDisabledDates is array of dates

var arrayDisabledDates=[...,...,..]

Comment: ok i think i explained it wrong.This code disabled all my datepicker.I want to make a validation to not choose selected day again.each day each appointment.So first, all dates should be available but when someone clicked on 15 june(just an example) and get appointment.No one can choose 15 june again.I think I should use code which is connected with my database because i keep dates of appointments in my db.

Comment: but where can i add my connection to database to check if that date is already choosen?