# Disable dates from datepicker

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a datepicker:

```
            <input required type="datetime-local" asp-for="BookStartDate" 
            min="@DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + "T09:00")" 
            max="2025-12-30T16:30" 
            value="@DateTime.Now.AddDays(+2).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + "T09:00")" />
```

Is there a way to disable dates that are already stored in mydatabase? This is a booking app so, if the date was booked by other user, I want it to be disabled (not available to pick). Booked date TBL looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookedDate](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[BkdDate] [datetime] NULL,
[BkdBy] [nchar](10) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: check this if this answers your requirement :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489696/how-to-disabled-selected-date-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: The only way is to make a list of all dates and then delete the ones already booked.

Comment: @fahad : Your link only shows how to disable dates.  Not to get the ones that are already booked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems hard to disable a specific day just by using `type="datetime-local"`, its most common use is to set max and min values to disable out-of range dates.

Perhaps you can add an `onchange` event to the input to get the current value. If the value already exists, a pop-up box is used to alert you.

You can also use the jquery date picker, and then use the beforeShowDay property to disable some dates. For example,

```
//Pass your stored date to the view
var unavailableDates = ["2022-10-14", "2022-10-15", "2022-10-16"];
    
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
                if(unavailableDates.indexOf(dmy) != -1){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```